# Jquery/Magento - triggering a select change

Tags: jquery, magento

I have some configurable products in my magento shop.

When I choose a configurable option (say color), the next select is then updated based on this.

However, i need this to happen programatically so i am using Jquery to automatically change the option.

```
$j(selectbox).change(); // called after updating the select
```

this however, does not trigger the next select being populated, although doing it manually does.
I can't figure out how to do this via Jquery.

I've also tried:

```
$j(selectbox).trigger('change');
```

any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, maybe try like something this: $(selectbox).css("color","#fff"); this is going to change the selectbox color to white

Answer (score 0):

I went ahead and used event.simulate.js, apparently the jquery trigger() won't allow me to do what I wanted